# Problems Connecting MSN with empathy

Tags: 11.10, empathy, connection, msn

I don't know if I am the only one with this bug, but I can't use my MSN account with a freshly installed Ubuntu 11.10 with Empathy. It used to work with my Arch Linux, but now with Ubuntu, it continuously tries to connect but nothing happens.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Without uninstalling anything, you can fix this by changing a line in the file 
`/usr/share/pyshared/papyon/service/description/AB/__init__.py`.

Edit it as root by running:

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/pyshared/papyon/service/description/AB/__init__.py
```

Change line 23 from this:

```
url = "http://contacts.msn.com/abservice/abservice.asmx"
```

To this:

```
url = "https://local-bay.contacts.msn.com/abservice/abservice.asmx"
```

Or to this:

```
url = "https://local-sn.contacts.msn.com/abservice/abservice.asmx"
```

Reboot and test it, it's working for me!

Comment: That worked for me as well!

Comment: Can you elaborate on what is this option and why it solves the problem?

Comment: papyon seems to be a MSN plugin for empathy or some empathy protocol helper. This plugin tryes to connect to a MSN web service to login and get your buddy list through some XML SOAP magic. It seems that microsoft MSN engineers changed the URL of that web service and for that, many non official MSN clients got problems to login and get the Buddy list. With this change, you tell papyon where the webservice is and it works, at least for me.

Comment: i confirm it worked for me too! and no reboot required. thanks

Comment: is there a way to get the url for other locations? That one does not work for me. :/

Comment: This didn't work for me on 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

```
sudo apt-get remove telepathy-butterfly
```

Remove your MSN account and add it again, it worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Just open the terminal and enter this command:

```
sudo apt-get install msn-pecan
```

Then after it finishes installing, choose msn-pecan for your email instead of MSN messenger and it will work.

Answer (score 1):

This happened on my PC at the weekend.  I disabled the account, waited 10 seconds and then re-enabled the account.  MSN network connected straight away.